# Get string value of Alamofire AFError error Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm making a request to my server with AlamoFire, and I have a setup something like this, where "self.error" is a String variable.

```
                    session.request("https://localhost:3000/my-route", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let result):
                              print("nice", result)                         
                            
                        case .failure(let err):
                            self.error = err //self.error is a String state variable
                            print("failure")
                        }
                       }
```

However, I get the (sensible) error "Cannot assign value of type 'AFError' to type 'String'", because I'm trying to set `self.error = err`, and `err` is of type AFError, whereas self.error is a String state variable.

I realize I could just do something like self.error = "There was an error", but I'd like to provide the user with some feedback as to what the error actually was, and I can't seem to find the correct properties (i.e. something like err.stringValue, err.description, etc.) to do so. Seems like there's some source code here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/AFError.swift but I'm not sure how this relates to the string value I'd like to obtain.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases you can always use String interpolation e.g. `self.error = "\(err)"`, but this is not a good idea because err is not just a string and could contain something like:

`sessionTaskFailed(error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x280e37750 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <78576E38-D021-4ADC-87D4-1C9D81FF0E3A>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=( "LocalDataTask <78576E38-D021-4ADC-87D4-1C9D81FF0E3A>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:3000/my-route, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:3000/my-route, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})`

Like @Menaim already mentioned, you can use `err.localizedDescription`, then you could get something like `URLSessionTask failed with error: Could not connect to the server.`

Generally, I would not pass the error directly to the user. This depends at your users, but do they really should know what e.g. `URLSessionTask` is?

In my opinion you should define error string for user, that every user can understand and you should log `err.localizedDescription` to the console, so you can know what is happening.

If your app supports many languages, you can define localizable.strings files and translate the errors.

**If you do this `print("failure")`, every time you have an error, how can you distinguish the errors?**

My suggestion would be something like:

```
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.error = "There was an error connecting to the server"
                    print("Failed to connect to backend: \(err.localizedDescription)")
```

Comment: yeah thank you! This is what I ended up doing -- I gave the user a more general error and printed out something to the console for development/debugging purposes!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `err.localizedDescription` or you can get the error in the completion of the function and return it `completion(error)`

Comment: cool thanks! Thought .localizedDescription was only for Firebase but guess not!